# CoffeeScript object properties and closures

Tags: javascript, variables, closures, coffeescript

I have a class MapHandler.

I created an object myMaphandler = new MapHandler and called initialize method.
But @userLocationMarker.getPosition() is returning null :(

If I'll comment alert and call @userLocationMarker.getPosition() from Chrome JS console I getting necessary coordinates.

```
class window.MapHandler

  initialize: (centerLocation) ->
    @makeMap(centerLocation)
    @defineUserLocation()
    alert @userLocationMarker.getPosition()


  makeMap: (centerLocation) ->
    myOptions =
      zoom: 14
      center: centerLocation
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    @map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions)


  placeMarker: (location, icon_path) ->
    if icon_path
      markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon_path, null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(25, 25))
    else
      markerImage = null
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      position: location
      map: @map
      icon: markerImage)

  defineUserLocation: () ->
    @userLocationMarker = @placeMarker(null, null)

    handleMap = (position) =>
      pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        map: @map
        position: pos
        content: 'Если это не ваше местоположение - передвиньте маркер'
      )
      @map.setCenter(pos)
      @userLocationMarker.setPosition(pos)

    if navigator.geolocation
      @userPosition = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPositon(
        handleMap
      )
```

[LINK](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20window.MapHandler%0A%0A%20%20initialize%3A%20%28centerLocation%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40makeMap%28centerLocation%29%0A%20%20%20%20%40defineUserLocation%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20alert%20%40userLocationMarker.getPosition%28%29%0A%0A%0A%20%20makeMap%3A%20%28centerLocation%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20myOptions%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20zoom%3A%2014%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20center%3A%20centerLocation%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20mapTypeId%3A%20google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP%0A%20%20%20%20%40map%20%3D%20new%20google.maps.Map%28document.getElementById%28%22map_canvas%22%29%2C%20myOptions%29%0A%0A%0A%20%20placeMarker%3A%20%28location%2C%20icon_path%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20if%20icon_path%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20markerImage%20%3D%20new%20google.maps.MarkerImage%28icon_path%2C%20null%2C%20null%2C%20null%2C%20new%20google.maps.Size%2825%2C%2025%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20markerImage%20%3D%20null%0A%20%20%20%20marker%20%3D%20new%20google.maps.Marker%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20location%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20map%3A%20%40map%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20icon%3A%20markerImage%29%0A%0A%20%20defineUserLocation%3A%20%28%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40userLocationMarker%20%3D%20%40placeMarker%28null%2C%20null%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20handleMap%20%3D%20%28position%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20pos%20%3D%20new%20google.maps.LatLng%28position.coords.latitude%2C%20position.coords.longitude%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20infowindow%20%3D%20new%20google.maps.InfoWindow%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%3A%20%40map%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20position%3A%20pos%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20%27%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20-%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%27%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40map.setCenter%28pos%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40userLocationMarker.setPosition%28pos%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20navigator.geolocation%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40userPosition%20%3D%20navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPositon%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20handleMap%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%29)

Why this occurs and what I should do for avoiding this situation?

Comment: Just to clarify.. console.log(@userLocationMarker.getPosition()) gives you the correct data?  I feel like there is something missing from your post... are you using a library?

Comment: Okay, well where exactly is getPosition defined?

Comment: This is a Google Maps API and this method from Marker class.

Comment: When I call from JS console myMapHandler.userLocationMarker.getPosition()
I get:
Q
Pa: 54.7242243
Qa: 20.46035059999997
__proto__: Q

Comment: Well, you're setting the userLocationMarker to null when you call defineUserLocation before you try to alert it... @userLocationMarker = @placeMarker(null, null)  I don't see where that would get changed to your position.  It's kind of hard to troubleshoot something like this without actually testing it myself.  Throw in alerts to make sure your location is being set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You initialize `@userLocationMarker` with a `null` position:

```
@userLocationMarker = @placeMarker(null, null)
```

And then you set the "real" positon in `handleMap`:

```
handleMap = (position) =>
  #...
  @userLocationMarker.setPosition(pos)
```

which is used as a callback for `getCurrentPosition`:

```
if navigator.geolocation
  @userPosition = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    handleMap
  )
```

The problem is that `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous so your `alert` is getting called before `handleMap` has been called by `getCurrentPosition`. Anything that depends on what `getCurrentPosition` does has to be in the `handleMap` callback or they need to be prepared to deal with data that hasn't arrived yet.

There's also a typo in your example code, you spelled `getCurrentPosition` wrong in your `if navigator.geolocation` block.

By the time you try checking the position from the JavaScript console, `getCurrentPosition` has called `handleMap` and `@userLocationMarker` will have had its position properly initialized.

Comment: @Trevor: Thought you might feel lonely hoarding all the CoffeeScript points :)